# How a custom token be transferred to hard wallets?

Tags: assets, wallets, token-wallet

Say I create a token ABC via programming. It is generated on Horizon and gives me Seed and Password. Now I want to have a few ABC coin on my personal wallet. What steps do I need that I can transfer it to my Stellar compatible wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any token can be sent with [a payment operation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#payment). Creating a payment operation requires a destination address, an asset, and an amount. From the issuing account, submit a transaction with a payment to your wallet. The account you're sending to needs to have a [trustline](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#trustlines) to the asset.